# Python removed and re-installed; strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-3.x, archlinux

I've recently upgraded arch from 32 to 64 bit and found pip wouldn't let me install 64 bit packages as old python was 32 bit. I therefore did the following to force a 64 bit python install:

```
sudo pacman -Rsc python
sudo pacman -S python
```

However, now I get:

```
[james@tryptophan bin]$ python
-bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

If I ls-l:

```
[james@tryptophan bin]$ ls -l /usr/bin/pyth*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     7 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python -> python3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Dec 21 07:25 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  5588 Dec 21 07:26 /usr/bin/python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1681 Dec 21 07:25 /usr/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Dec 21 07:25 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 10392 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> python3.6m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 10392 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  3146 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    16 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    14 Jan 16 11:14 /usr/bin/python-config -> python3-config
```

It's peculiar because it looks like python is linked to python3, which is linked to python3.6, and /usr/bin/python3.6 seems to exist - indeed I can tab-complete it.

However, if I try to execute it:

```
[james@tryptophan bin]$ /usr/bin/python3.6
-bash: /usr/bin/python3.6: No such file or directory
```

Bash claims it doesn't exist! Anyone got any ideas what's going on?

Comment: What is the output of `ldd /usr/bin/python3.6`?

Comment: `[james@tryptophan bin]$ ldd /usr/bin/python3.6
 not a dynamic executable` So I guess it's a link too... ? But I'm not sure what to...

Comment: No, it's not a link, because then ls would have shown it as such. Most likely a script or a file in another executable format. Would you mind posting the output of `file /usr/bin/python3.6; head -n 3 /usr/bin/python3.6` as well?

Comment: Yep of course, it's at: http://pastebin.com/fGJebkX8

Comment: Are you sure you're running a 64 bit system already? I apologize for querying for yet another output, but what do you get with `uname -a`?

Comment: `[james@tryptophan bin]$ uname -a
Linux tryptophan 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78 #1 SMP Tue Nov 1 14:51:21 EDT 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136067/discussion-between-phihag-and-james).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by an incomplete migration to 64 bit linux; I had a 64 bit linux kernel but with a 32 bit userland as I'd not completed every step of method 2 within https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Migrating_between_architectures